# FileReader readAsText stored file content as string in result property, but when console.log this result, nothing returned.

Tags: javascript, html, file, filereader

In HTML file, I created a button to upload files:

```
 <span id='upload' class="btn btn-default btn-file">Upload<input type="file" id="input" onchange="this.files"></span>
```

In Javascript File:

```
//this event click event on the upload buttom, and parse filelist to handleFiles function:
 var upload_btn = document.getElementById('upload');
    if (upload_btn) {
      //this.uploadSet.bind(this);
          var inputElement = document.getElementById("input");
          upload_btn.onclick = inputElement.addEventListener("change", this.handleFiles, false);
    }
```

handleFiles function:

```
handleFiles: function() {
  var fileList = this.files; /* now you can work with the file list */
  console.log(fileList);
  var file = fileList[0];
  var fr = new FileReader();

 fr.readAsText(file,"utf-8");

  console.dir(fr);

  }
```

In browser console, it returns the filereader object with a property named "result", which contains the text of the file content. In console, it looks like this:

```
FileReader{}
  error: null
  onabort: null
  onerror: null
  onload: null
  onloadend: null
  onloadstart: null
  onprogress: null
  readyState: 2
  result: "!Name: acorn↵!↵.O.....↵...O...↵OO..OOO↵"
  __proto__: FileReader
```

However, when I tried to do console.log(fr.result), the console returned nothing. And it didn't throw an error. I am not sure what went wrong here. Is there a way I can read this result from the FileReader?

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `label` element including `for="input"` attribute for `span` element , call single handler for `onchange` event of `input` element

```js
var upload = document.getElementById("upload");

function handleFiles(e) {

  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function(e) {
    console.dir(e.target.result);
  }

  reader.readAsText(e.target.files[0])

}

upload.onchange = handleFiles;
```

```css
label input {
  visibility:hidden; 
}
```

```html
<label for="input" id='upload' class="btn btn-default btn-file">Upload<input type="file" id="input" accepts="text/plain"></label>
```